# How to flush uri out of imageview which is causing program to crash

Tags: android, arrays, imageview, uri

How would i be able to flush the memory out of the image view from a previous uri source that is stored in the image view? 
Here is my code so far :

```
ImageView a = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.a);
ImageView b=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.b);
ImageView c =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.c);


 Uri topImage = Uri.parse(top);
 Uri bottomImage = Uri.parse(bottom);
 Uri fwImage = Uri.parse(fw);

 a.setImageURI(topImage);
 b.setImageURI(bottomImage);
 c.setImageURI(fwImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recycling and setting null:

```
BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
bd.getBitmap().recycle();
iv.setImageDrawable(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you experience memory issue with imageViews, make sure you are loading the correct size of image into your imageView.

If your iamgeView is 200*200 and your image is 2000*2000, you need to downsample it instead of loading it directly with its Uri.

Check this link http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html